# In Android (Java) get all reviews from documents which contain the current user's email address

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my collection of eateries, each eatery has a unique random ID. Within each eatery document there may be a field named 'reviews'. Each review is a map and is stored under a user's email address. Is there any way I can query the database as a whole and get all the reviews for one user email address? I've tried several things, such as storing the user email as a field within the map and using dot notation to try and pull out the review, but to no avail. The best I've come up with so far:

```
db.collection("eateries")
    .whereEqualTo("reviews" , userEmail)
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            Log.d(TAG, "restoreReviews onComplete: task.getResult(): " + task.getResult().size());

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                Log.d(TAG, "restoreReviews onComplete: task was successful");

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                }

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "restoreReviews Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Just to reiterate, reviews contains maps of review objects (which are in turn also maps):

[image]

A user could leave reviews for lots of eateries (in other documents) and I'd like to retrieve them all. eateriesTest is just a dummy collection to show the types of documents I'm querying, without displaying users' actual email addresses. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate your document structure in more detail.  The written description you have now isn't detailed enough - a diagram would be better.

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses - I've updated with a screenshot of my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your database does not allow for the kind of query you're trying to do.  Firestore can't query for the existence of keys within a map field.  It can only query on the values of map keys.

You will have to add the email addresses to the document in a way that can actually be queried.  For example, they could be stored as individual elements of an array type field, and filtered with an [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) query.  It's common to duplicate information like this in order to satisfy your queries.

For example, if you have an array field "reviewers" with only the strings of each email, you could filter them like this:

```
.whereArrayContains("reviewers" , userEmail)
```

Comment: Thanks Doug. I've added an ArrayList of user emails to each eatery document and have queried them exactly as you've shown above. I now get all the document in a snapshot and can go through and pull the info I need.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to query an array of reviews the whereEqualTo method doesnt do what youre looking for here. If you replace it with whereArrayContains() method that should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. It's a map of reviews currently. Would I be better changing this to an Array? Or is there any way to retrieve the details with the current schema?

Comment: I justr noticed that you have collections "eateries" and "eateries_test". in the code you have above you're querying eateries but the screenshot you sent is eateries_test.

Comment: Just created the test collection for the purpose of creating the screenshot. I'm querying the eateries collection which contains the same type of objects.

Comment: After looking into what ive wrote in the past im pretty sure you stilll have to use array-contains with maps

Comment: Ok, brilliant, thanks. I'm going to come back to this tomorrow morning and see if I can get it working with whereArrayContains() with fresh eyes! Will update after trying again.

Comment: Thanks for your help Trevor. It was whereArrayContains() that I needed to use!

Comment: Yay! Im glad that I could help!